# Why is $\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{Var}(X_{(n)})$ for i.i.d $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim U(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution, variance, order-statistics

This is an order statistics question. I'm using the notation found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic.

We have $n$ IID random variables $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ that are uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $X_{(n)} = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.

I am asked to reason that $\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{Var}(X_{(n)})$ without resorting to calculations. So it seems some kind of intuitive answer is wanted.

I'm given the hint that $\operatorname{Var}(x) =\operatorname{Var}(1-x)$ for any random variable $x$, but it's not obvious to me how this is helpful.

I know that 
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)}) = E[X_{(1)}^2] - E[X_{(1)}]^2 \\
\operatorname{Var}(X_{(n)}) = E[X_{(n)}^2] - E[X_{(n)}]^2
$$

We known that $E[X_1] = \cdots = E[X_n] = 0.5$.

Intuition tells me that $E[X_{(1)}]$ and $E[X_{(n)}]$ are symmetrically situated about 0.5, i.e, 
$$
0.5 - E[X_{(1)}] = E[X_{(n)}] - 0.5 \\
1 = E[X_{(1)}] + E[X_{(n)}]
$$
Not sure if this helps. I still can't figure out how $\operatorname{Var}(x) = \operatorname{Var}(1-x)$ is helpful. 
Am I going in the right correction with this expected value reasoning?

Honestly, it's kind of intuitive to me that $\operatorname{Var}(X_{(1)})=\operatorname{Var}(X_{(n)})$ by symmetry, but I'm having a hard time putting it into words while incorporating the hint.

Comment: This also follows from the fact that $X_i-\frac12$ has the same distribution as $\frac12-X_i$ (since the distribution is symmetric about $1/2$), so that $X_{(n)}-\frac12$ has the same distribution as $\frac12-X_{(1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_k=1-X_k$.  $Y_k$ has the same distribution as $X_k$.  (define $Y_{(1)}$ and $Y_{(n)}$ using the same min and max notation).

Therefore $var(Y_{(1)})=var(X_{(1)})$.  Meanwhile $Y_{(1)}=X_{(n)}$ and $Y_{(n)}=X_{(1)}$

As a result $var(X_{(n)})=var(X_{(1)})=var(Y_{(n)})=var(Y_{(1)})$

Comment: I like this proof. This relies on us knowing that $Y_{(1)} = X_{(n)}$ and $Y_{(n)} = X_{(1)}$, which further relies on us knowing that $E[X_{(1)}] - 0 = 1- E[X_{(n)}]$, the symmetry argument I made earlier. Is this obvious by inspection, or does this need to be proven some how?

Comment: $Y_{(1)}$ is the minimum of {$Y_k=1-X_k$} which  corresponds to the maximum of {$X_k$} which is  $X_{(n)}$.  Essentially changing the sign of all $X_k$ switches max and min.

Comment: Isn't $Y_{(1)}=1-X_{(n)}$ and $Y_{(n)}=1-X_{(1)}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom   You are correct.  The variance conclusion still holds, since var(x)=var(1-x) for any random variable x.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Isn't $Y_{(1)} = X_{(1)}$?

Comment: @David No.  $Y_{(1)}$ is the min of the collection $1-X_k$, which is $1-X_{(n)}$ leading to $var(Y_{(1)})=var(X_{(n)})$

Comment: Right. But isn't the min of the collection $1-X_k$ equal to the min of the collection $X_k$, which is $X_{(1)}$? I believe $1-X_{(n)}$ = $X_{(1)}$, by symmetry.

Comment: @David No:  because of minus sign, min and max are switched.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Hmm, maybe I misunderstand the notation. Is $Y_{(1)}$ the minimum value from $\{Y_1, \cdots, Y_n \}$? The distribution of $\{X_1, \cdots, X_n\}$ should be identical to  $\{Y_1, \cdots, Y_n \}$, so that's why I think $Y_{(1)} = X_{(1)}$

Comment: $Y_{(1)}$ is the minimum, so it will $=1-X_{(n)}$, since $X_{(n)}$ is the max.

Comment: Right I understand that. But I think what I'm trying to get at is, isn't $1-X_{(n)} = X{(1)}$ by symmetry? Hence, $X_{(1)} = Y_{(1)}$

Comment: Why do you think $1-X_{(n)}=X_{(1)}$?  The first is $1-$max, while the second is min.

Comment: Sorry I'm thinking of their expected values. I think  $1-E[X_{(n)}] = E[X_{(1)}]$ and not $1-X_{(n)} = 1-X{(1)}$.

Comment: $E(X_k)=E(1-X_j)=0.5$ for all j and k.